# После парсинга в файле получились не разборчивые символы, также как вместо p,a,s,s добавлять просто pass

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, csv

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].csv текст   `import requests`

```
 import time
 import csv

 version = 5.95
 domain = 'hearthstone'
 count = 100
 offset = 10
 all_posts = []


def gp_parse():
    token = input()
    version = 5.95
    domain = 'hearthstone'
    count = 100
    offset = 0
    all_posts = []
    a = []

    response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get', params={'access_token': token,
                                                                          'v': version,
                                                                          'domain': domain,
                                                                          'count': count,
                                                                          'offset': offset})
    while offset < 1000:
        data = response.json()['response']['items']
        offset+= 100
        all_posts.extend(data)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if len(all_posts) not in a:
            a.append(len(all_posts))
            print(len(all_posts))
        else:
            pass

    return all_posts


all_posts = gp_parse()


def file_writer(all_posts):
    p = 'pass'
    with open('group_parse.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        a_pen.writerow(('id владельца', 'описание поста', 'лайки', 'комментарии', 'репосты', 'просмотры'))
        for post in all_posts:
            try:
                a_pen.writerow((post['owner_id'], post['text'], post['likes']['count'], post['comments']['count'],
                                post['reposts']['count'], post['views']['count']
                                )).text

            except:
                (csv.Error)
            a_pen.writerow((p))


all_posts = gp_parse()
file_writer(all_posts)
```

Comment: и если не сложно как при цикле у меня идёт 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 100 200 и т.д и в конце результат. Как это убрать.

Comment: Что Вы хотите сделать этим циклом? Зачем Вам там `time.sleep()`? Логика мутная

Comment: Приведите пример файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас сбита кодировка. Сходу сложно сказать, какая конкретно именно у Вас. Попробуйте воспользоваться [этим](https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/) декодером. Похоже на `cp1251`. Попробуйте `KOIR-8`, либо `unicode`.

Кроме того, кажется, что Ваш csv-файл, очень странный. Это не положе на таблицу. Кажется, что Вы его используете не по назначению. Если Вы всё же хотите использовать csv, попробуйте воспользоваться [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/). Это чудесная библиотека для работы с табличными данными. Она замечательно сохраняет данные, в т.ч. в csv.

Отказываясь от этой библиотеки или подобной ей, Вы обрекаете себя на проблему при работе с csv, в частности, Вы рискуете не соблюсти формат записи и Ваш файл окажется инвалидным. Велик риск, что Вы обнаружите это не сразу. А по прошествии времени, восстановить данные, которые будут в нём окажется сложным. Это может произойти, например, потому что API яндекса поменялось или же Ваш код потерялся.

Что касается кода, то не стоит объявлять глобальные переменные. Это плохая практика, которая ухудшает читаемость кода, а также делает невозможным тестирование (если оно вдруг понадобится). Привыкать к этому не стоит. Тогда Ваша функция становится зависимой от многих переменных, которые неочевидно, откуда берутся. Например, зачем `all_posts` объявлять во вне, когда вы эти же переменные переопределяете внутри тела функции:

```
def gp_parse():
    token = input()
    version = 5.95
    domain = 'hearthstone'
    count = 100
    offset = 0
    all_posts = []
    a = []

    response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get', params={'access_token': token,
                                                                          'v': version,
                                                                          'domain': domain,
                                                                          'count': count,
                                                                          'offset': offset})
```

С помощью pandas, мы можем получить, например, следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('group_parsev.csv')
columns = ['id владельца', 'описание поста', 'лайки', 'комментарии']
df.iloc[1::2] = float('nan')
df = df.dropna()
df['Статус'] = 'pass'
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95128/discussion-on-answer-by-hedgehogues-------).

Comment: Ты то изображение получил с помощью этого кода? или что-то дописывал а то у меня просто 0 (результат)